# SQL CONTAINSTABLE with stop words

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, contains

We are having an issue with what I think is related to stop words. We have a table called `SearchData` that has a column of search terms (column also called `searchData`). We are using a `CONTAINSTABLE` on that column *WHERE* that column *CONTAINS* our search term.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    SearchData sd WITH(NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    CONTAINSTABLE(SearchData, searchData, @SearchString) ftt
    ON sd.resultGUID = ftt.[KEY]
WHERE CONTAINS(sd.SearchData, @SearchString)
ORDER BY Rank DESC;
```

This seems to be working great, the issue is when `@SearchString` starts with the word `the` (only word we have noticed so far). For example we have a record that has `The Guitar Room` in the `SearchData` column. When we search `guitar room` it pops up, when we search `the guitar room` nothing shows up.

Would this be related to *stop words*? Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: I've had problems with stop words as well--probably because I didn't fully research the problem enough.  :(  One option is to turn the stop list off for a particular table.  But you may fix one problem and introduce several others...

Comment: I actually found the solution. I created a custom stoplist from the system list, deleted 'the' from the list then assigned the list to the fulltext catalog. Works great!

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than my suggestion of turning off the stop list.  But will this be the start of a game of "whack-a-mole"?  You whacked "the"...what's next?

Comment: You couldn't have been more right. I have been having to delete lots of "words" from the list. haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this particular issue was simply deleting the entire list of stop words. Thanks!